# Does "kindly do the reimbursement" need an article?

Tags: grammaticality, definite-article

I am writing a reimbursement letter:

> I booked train ticket for Dr.David journey on 19.Apr.2016 and the ticket is attached for your kind perusal.
>
> I request you to **kindly do the reimbursement** for the same.

I'm confused about whether I should say:

> kindly do **the** reimbursement for the same

or

> kindly do reimbursement for the same

Which one is makes sense in this context?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is it correct? Kindly verify the content.

Comment: General proofreading questions are off-topic.  If you have a specific concern such as if "reimbursement" is the correct word, or if "perusal" makes sense in this context, etc.; then you can ask here.  How the question stands, it is off-topic. (By the way, welcome!  It's great to see new people interested in learning English.  For more help, see [what's on topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)

Comment: kindly do the reimbursement for the same or Kindly do reimbursement ...which one is makes sense in this context

Comment: To make sure that others notice what your question is (both to get more answers and to keep this question from being closed), I would suggest that you [edit] this post with what your specific question is.

Comment: We have a verb, **reimburse**. It takes an object.  *Kindly reimburse the same.* Or an indirect object.  *Kindly reimburse me for the same.*

Answer (score -1):

Both of these sentences are needing reconstruction.  "I booked train ticket for Dr.David journey on 19.Apr.2016 and the ticket is attached for your kind perusal.", would read more clearly as, "I booked a train ticket for Dr. David's journey on 19.Apr.2016.  The Ticket is attached."  "for your perusal" is not needed.  The fact that the ticket is attached tells the person to look for the ticket.  You need an apostrophe after "David", to show that the trip is for Dr. David.  Notice that you need a space after "Dr.".  You also have two thoughts in one sentence that is better broken into two sentences.

The second sentence, "I request you to kindly do the reimbursement for the same.", would be much clearer if you said, "Please send reimbursement for the ticket", or "Please reimburse me".  "I request you to kindly" is considered overly flowery.  "do the reimbursement" is incorrect in that one does not "do" a reimbursement.  One can "make" or "send" a reimbursement, but not "do" one.  "for the same" is redundant because there can only be one thing for which a reimbursement can be made.